# How to remove variables in plot_summs?

Tags: r, visualization

I use plot_summs to plot my regression coefficients. below is a reproducible sample. I want to do two things. First, I want to remove Frost and Murder from the graph. Second, I want to change the color of Illiteracy and Population to Green and Life Exp and HS Grad to red. I’d appreciate any help I can get here.

```
fit1 <- lm(Income ~ Frost + Illiteracy + Murder +
         Population + Area + Life Exp + HS Grad,
       data = states, weights = runif(50, 0.1, 3))
plot_summs(fit1, scale = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using the jtools package:

If I'm not wrong, plot_summ with scale - TRUE, scales the independent variables and plots the summary of the variable estimates, with mean as point and 2*SE as segments.

```
states2 <- states
states2[,-1] <- scale(states2[,-1]) # Considering first column is Income

fit2 <- lm(Income ~ ., data = states2, weights = runif(50, 0.1, 3))

df <- as.data.frame(summary(fit2)[["coefficients"]][-1,1:2])
df$variable <- rownames(df)

df <- df[!df$variable %in% c("Frost", "Murder"), ]


library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = variable, y = Estimate,
                 color = variable), size = 6) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = variable, xend = variable, 
                   y = Estimate - (2 * `Std. Error`),
                   yend = Estimate + (2 * `Std. Error`),
                   color = variable), lwd = 2) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Illiteracy" = "green","Population" = "green",
                                "Area" = "blue",
                                "`Life Exp`" = "red",  "`HS Grad`" = "red")) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_classic()
```